# I want to put into variables multiple value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

**I want to do this**

```
if ($(this).val() in (1,2,3) ) {
    ...
}
```

**I have tried this and it works but It's not what I want**

```
if ($(this).val()==1 || $(this).val()==2 || $(this).val()==3 ) {
    ...         
}
```

Comment: You could cache `$(this).val()` in a local variable, then your conditional expression would be both performant and readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array and [$.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/):

```
if ($.inArray(parseInt($(this).val()), [1, 2, 3]) > -1) {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I notice OP is using jQuery but this should work for anyone who isn't

```
if([1,2,3].indexOf(yourValue) > -1) {
    ...
}
```

Edit, Gah, beaten by Blazemonger by 20 seconds

Answer (score 1):

Attempting to synthesize information that is currently scattered in a number of different answers and comments... Your code is not working because of two things:

1. You are using `in` which checks for *keys*, not *values* in an array. Thus, for example, `3 in [1,2,3]` will be false, since `[1,2,3]` has keys (indices) `0,1,2`.
2. Quite possibly, your value is a string

The solution is to make sure that your value is of the right type, and to use the correct function.  There are two obvious choices:

```
indexOf         - returns the index of the (first) element that matches
inArray         - is available if you are using jQuery
```

Sample code:

```
var v = parseInt($(this).val());  // radix 10
var r = [1,2,3];                  // the values to check against

if(r.indexOf(v) > -1) {     // method 1

if($.inArray(v, r)) {       // method 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([1,2,3].indexOf($(this).val()) > -1) {
```

or

```
for (i in [1,2,3])
    if (i==$(this).val()) {
         ...
    }
```